# wxPython - cannot hide wxFrame for a desktop screenshot

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm very new to wxPython and working on a desktop screenshot utility. In short, user selects a rectangular region on their screen from and produce an image from it as most screenshot tools already do. Its all working except for the fact that I cannot get the main frame, and all it contains, to hide or close, so the screenshot image produced contains the overlay mask and dashed selection box.

FYI, screenshots are triggered by pressing the ENTER key. I have tried a vast number of ways to achieve this without luck. Hiding the frame, or destroying the panel first etc. makes no difference. However, if I break things up to two steps with button to proceed it all works fine so I am betting it's something small. I tried Refresh on the frame and panel as well. For what it's worth, my desktop environment if Linux KDE (latest ArchLinux rolling release).

Here is my code in full.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import wx, time

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class SelectableFrame(wx.Frame):
    c1 = None
    c2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, title=""):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos=(0, 0), size=wx.DisplaySize(), style=wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wx.NO_BORDER | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=self.GetSize())

        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseSelect)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnReset)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_COLOUR)

        self.SetTransparent(150)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.c2 = event.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseSelect(self, event):
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        key = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.Close()
        elif (key == wx.WXK_RETURN or key == wx.WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER) and self.RegionSelected():
            self.TakeScreenshot()
        event.Skip()

    def OnReset(self, event=None):
        wx.PaintDC(self.panel).Clear()
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        if not self.RegionSelected():
            return
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("white", 1, wx.LONG_DASH))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(100, 100, 100), wx.SOLID))

        dc.DrawRectangle(self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)

    def RegionSelected(self):
        if self.c1 is None or self.c2 is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def TakeScreenshot(self):
        if not self.RegionSelected():
            return
        wx.PaintDC(self.panel).Clear()
        self.Hide()
        self.Refresh()
        dcScreen = wx.ScreenDC()
        bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)
        memDC = wx.MemoryDC()
        memDC.SelectObject(bmp)
        memDC.Blit(0, 0, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y, dcScreen, self.c1.x, self.c1.y)
        memDC.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
        img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
        filename = "/tmp/ocr-screenshot-" + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + ".png"
        img.SaveFile(filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.Close()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class SelectableApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = SelectableFrame()
        self.frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

app = SelectableApp(False)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: you're probably reading from the screen before the hiding/closing has finished being done to the screen. i experimented with triggering the read off of events related to the window, but i'm still not sure that would be late enough.

Comment: You might have some luck with `wx.CallAfter` and `wx.CallLater`.  This doesn't run on my machine, so unfortunately I can't test.

Comment: It works like a charm on my windows 8 pc.